как объединить telethon и telebot при том, что главный скрипт telebot
у меня есть два скрипта
bot.py
import asyncio
import telebot
from main import send_message_telegram

Token = 'no'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(Token , parse_mode="HTML")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['text'])
def handle_text(message):
    message_text = "Test message"
    asyncio.run(send_message_telegram(message_text))

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Хеллоу")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['chat_id'])
def start(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.chat.id)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['message_id'])
def start(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.id)

print("Бота запущено")
bot.infinity_polling(none_stop=True)

и main.py
from telethon import TelegramClient

async def send_message_telegram(message_text):
    api_id = 'no'
    api_hash = 'no'
    bot_token = 'no'

    client = TelegramClient('Test2Session', api_id, api_hash)

    try:
        await client.start(bot_token=bot_token)

        chat_id = no

        await client.send_message(chat_id, message_text)
    finally:
        await client.disconnect()

запускаю я bot.py а он не выводит сообщение о старте бота. Я при помощи print() выяснил что ошибка в строчке
from main import send_message_telegram
что означает что ошибка в main.py. Потратил 3 часа и ничего так и не получается.
помогите , пожалуйста
ожидания от кода того, что он на команду text будет выводить сообщения в чат (в будущем я это заменю на получение конкретного сообщения по его id)
